# NullPointerException al generar gráfica

Tags: java

Estoy creando una gráfica con datos de la base de datos, pero cuando trato de generar el gráfico me sale este error:

**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException**

Creo que hay algo mal en mi método **createDataset**, pero no estoy seguro. Ese es el método:

```
private XYDataset createDataset(){
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Teste");
    conex.conectar();

    try{
    do{
        double rcv = conex.rs.getDouble("rcv_arena_verde"); // La primera línea que sale en el error
        double rth = conex.rs.getDouble("rth_arena_verde"); 
    series.add(rcv, rth);

    } while (conex.rs.next());
    }catch (SQLException ex){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao preencher grafico \n " +ex.getMessage());
    }

    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series); 
    return dataset;
}
```

La primera línea que sale en el error es la primera dentro del "**do**".

Utilizo los mismos parámetros/métodos de conexión con la base de datos en otras clases en el mismo proyecto y no tengo ningún problema, así que no creo que este sea el error. ¿Tal vez los estoy usando incorrectamente en esta clase?

Comment: Puedes mostrar donde tienes declarado el conex y donde haces el new de dicho conex?

Comment: Está al inicio de la clase: public class GraficosArenaProceso extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
ConexaoBanco conex = new ConexaoBanco();

Comment: "ConexaoBanco" es la clase dónde hago la conexión.